# how to write multiple exec arguments in ant

Tags: bash, ant, appium

I want to write an ant script that will

1. start up a new terminal
2. Change user
3. and run the Appium session

This is what i have so far but it doesn't do anything

```
    <exec executable="/bin/bash" os="${os.unix}" spawn="true">
        <arg value="-c" />
        <arg value="gnome-terminal su appium" />
        <arg value="appium &amp;" />
    </exec>
```

Answer (score 7):

And what is the value of the property `${os.unix}`? If you're going to use the `os` parameter, you usually give it a string constant and not a property value.

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash" os="unix" spawn="true">
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="gnome-terminal su appium" />
    <arg value="appium &amp;" />
</exec>
```

This way, you could have an `<exec>` task for all Unix style operating systems, and another `<exec>` task for all the other ones (Windows).

Also understand the difference between `<arg value="..."/>` and `<arg line="..."/>`. I don't know the exact command structure for `gnome-terminal`, but when you pass something as a `value`, you're passing it as a single parameter -- even if it has spaces in it. For example:

```
<exec executable="foo">
   <arg value="-f foo -b bar"/>
</exec>
```

Will execute as if I typed this in the command line:

```
$ foo "-f foo -b bar"   # This is one command with one parameter. Note the quotation marks!
```

If I do this:

```
<exec executable="foo">
   <arg line="-f foo -b bar"/>
</exec>
```

Will execute as if I typed this in the command line:

$ foo -f foo -b bar   # This is one command with four parameters

This is equivalent to the above Ant task:

```
<exec executable="foo">
   <arg value="-f"/>
   <arg value="foo"/>
   <arg value="-b"/>
   <arg value="bar"/>
</exec>
```

Currently, you're attempting to execute:

$ /bin/bash -c "gnome-terminal su appium" "appium &"

If this is what you want, fine. By the way, you could skip the whole /bin/bash stuff on Unix:

```
<exec executable="gnome-terminal" os="unix" spawn="true">
    <arg value="su appium"/>
    <arg value="appium &amp;"/>
</exec>
```

Comment: Nice one. Helpful !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<exec executable="/bin/bash" spawn="true" >
    <arg value="-c" />
    <arg value="x-terminal-emulator -e 'sudo -u appium appium'" />
</exec>
```

`os="${os.unix}"` seems incorrect, I've removed it completely.

`-c` and bash command needs to be in separate `arg` element.

`su` will start new shell. Use `sudo` with argument instead.

command passed to `gnome-terminal` needs to be quoted.

`x-terminal-emulator` should be more portable than `gnome-terminal`.

---

Actually, using bash doesn't seem to be necessary at all. Try:

```
<exec executable="x-terminal-emulator" spawn="true" >
    <arg value="-e" />
    <arg value="sudo -u appium appium" />
</exec>
```

Comment: Hi I tried doing this since i dont have x-terminal-emulator but when i run it, it does something and close the terminal right away. <exec executable="gnome-terminal" spawn="true" >
     <arg value="-e" />
     <arg value="sudo -u appium appium" />
</exec>. Also, where can i put in the command appium & in order to start appium?

Comment: If you use `appium&` instead of `appium`, your terminal will start `appium` in background and close right away. Try executing `sudo -u appium appium` in your current terminal and see why it's not working correctly.

Comment: Try absolute path to appium e.g: `sudo -u appium /something/bin/appium`. Or, add -i option: `sudo -iu appium appium`

Comment: ok with this <exec executable="/bin/bash" os="${os.unix}" spawn="true" >
            <arg value="-c" />
            <arg value="gnome-terminal -x su appium" />
            <arg value="appium" />
        </exec> it starts up new terminal with changed user but it doesn't run "appium"

Comment: `su appium` will start a new shell. Next command can be executed only after that shell is closed. Use `sudo` as I described or `su` with `-c` option to execute `appium` instead of shell.